# Searchview in widgets

Tags: android

I am new to android and I wanted to make an android widget which contains searchview.
I want to create an EditText in widget and the search results to display in homescreen only with a drop down list or something. 
I'm aware of widgets but I can not find something like this. Is this possible?
Thank you!

Comment: For the dropdown you can use a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Support for EditText in app widgets is currently not available in RemoteView.So it means you cant use edittext text.But you can use TextView and change its style to Edittext.

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    style="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
  </TextView>
```

A way to do this is to make a tap on your widget start a new activity (standard) and to make this activity fully transparent. There are ways to retrieve your widget's position, so that you can position a TextView in your activity on top of your widget. Make a tap outside of your TextView close the activity. I think this is what the Google search widget does.